# Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0x56557055 in final ()

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, nasm

I am writing a calculator. It works fine if I end the process right after the answer is printed, however I get this error if I want to add one of the subMethods (add, sub, mult, div) to return to the main method.

In the data section I have this to represent the answer

```
final: db "Answer=%d", 10, 0 ;setup for final printed string (printf)
```

This is one instance where the seg fault is being thrown

```
add:

add eax,ebx ;add eax and ebx
push eax ;push final eax value to stack
push dword final ;pushes final string using eax as param
call printf ;call printf using final as param
ret ;return
```

The add method is being called here

```
cmp ecx, 1 ;compare method value and 1 (if ecx - 1 == 0)
je add ;jumps to add function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. in add, it pushes two values on the stack before calling printf but it doesn’t remove them before the ret. Put “add esp, 8” after the call to printf before the ret.
2. In order to be able to return from add, you need to jump to it with a “call” instruction, not a jmp or jcc.

Alternatively you could just change the “ret” in add to “jmp <some-label-in-main>”. This would effectively make the add code part of main rather than a separate function.